# Assign javascript variable to php variable and post it on another page

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

Comment: Ajax added
Assign javascript variable to php variable and post it on another page

I use the Fullcalendar (javascript). When you click on the event it opens a form with its content.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {    

content.val(calEvent.content); //content of event
$('#event').show(); 
formOpen('edit');

},
```

I want to do that when you click on the event its opens another php page and displayed its data in it.I want to post value through the session,but i dont know how to assign javascript variable to php variable.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

var content = content.val();

<?php
print <<<HERE
location.href = 'anotherpage.php?id=$_SESSION[id]';
HERE;
?>

<?php
$content = content;
$_SESSION['content'] = $content;
?> 

},
```

P.S: ajax did not work because it seems that i have a bit of a particular situation.

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "anotherpage.php",
    data: {content: content.val()},

  });
Anotherpage.php

<?php
    $content = $_POST['content'];
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a problem only with reading `$_SESSION['id']`?

Comment: @ettanany I have a problem with this line (if i do everything correct): $content = content. If i write this: $content = "1",everything is working but i need to post "content.val()" variable.

Comment: I think that's not possible that way. The only solution I can imagine is to add your content var in the current page url (if content does not contain a lot of data) then read it in your php code with `$_GET`. You can also use forms to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use AJAX :**

ajax will send data under the hood.

**Ajax framework :**

Add this frame work under `<script>` on your calender page.

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
        return true;    
    }
}
```

**How to use :**

On your calendar page :

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

var content = content.val();

var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "Currunt_page_url.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {

            }
        }
//sends data by POST method to ur url page
        ajax.send("contents="+contents);

}
```

Add this at start of your calendar page :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['contents'])){
//save data of contents into session
$SESSION['contents']=$_POST['contents'];
location.header='URL_of_php_page.php';
//access session['id']/session['contents'] on your php page though session variables.
exit();

}
?>
```

Comment: You want safer side right ? so why dont you use hashing technique so it will hashe your content string ?

Comment: if I hash data,they will not be visible in the search box?

Comment: If you hash data it will be visible but no one can understand it , it will looking like some one pressing random keys on keyboard

Comment: I would not like this. Can it be done using Ajax? I will add Ajax code that I tried to use, but instead of a calendar page immediately appeared another page.

Comment: Ok so add your ajax code and i will edit my answer to ajax

Comment: Or give me few moments so i will give u a ajax script  , and how to send data using it

Comment: i saw your ajax reccomendations but when i approve edits it is gone,where can i find it?

Comment: Wait wait i am making things correct , I think there was some error in stack , give me a min

Comment: There is the same thing that I described in the question. I add Ajax functions on the calendar page. Currunt_page_url.php:calendarpage.php. I add the php code at the beginning of the calendar page. I think it's because of the sessions, you need to add session id to the link. I tried, but it does not help.

Comment: i was wrong,it is dont do anything, calendar just dissappears because of errors in the code

Comment: no...it didt post data just staying on the calendar page without interface

Comment: ok ,  open your google crome or nay browser and send me errors from console of browser iwll seewhat ican do

Comment: I do not want to bother you anymore, I will try to figure it out by myself, thank you for your help!